# Catch route with .html constraint and menupath(*) in .net Core

Tags: routes, asp.net-core

I am struggeling to achive the same routing in my .net core project, as i have in my mvc projects.

In my mvc projects i have the following routes caching menuPath and menuPath with pageurl. But as you can see im using a class named greedyroute in order to have 2 routes with (*).

```
  routes.Add(
                new GreedyRoute("{*menuPath}/{pageUrl}",
                new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Page", action = "Index" }),
                new RouteValueDictionary(new { pageUrl = @"[0-9a-zA-ZøæåØÆÅ+_-]+.html" }),
                new MvcRouteHandler()));

            routes.Add(
                new GreedyRoute("{*menuPath}",
                new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Page", action = "List" }),
                new MvcRouteHandler()));
```

How can i achieve the same result in a asp .net core project?

I did try the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "page",
    template: "{*menuPath}/{pageUrl}",
    constraints: new { pageUrl = @"[0-9a-zA-ZøæåØÆÅ+_-]+.html" },
    defaults: new { controller = "Page", action = "Index" });

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "listpage",
    template: "{*menuPath}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Page", action = "List" });
```

but that gives me this error:

Additional information: A catch-all parameter can only appear as the last segment of the route template.

**Examples of paths when the routing actually works:**

/stars/jupiter.html *routes to index method and menupath = /stars and pageurl = jupiter.html*

/stars/randomname/jupiter.html *routes to index method and menupath= /stars/randomname and pageurl = jupiter.html*

/stars/all-stars *routes to list method and menuPath = /stars/all-stars.*

And, menuPath is dynamic.

Comment: The error message is very clear. You can't do this. However if `menuPath` format is `{something}/{otherthing?}` then somehow you could achieve your goal.

Comment: You are right, and I know what the errormessage means, but when using greedyroute in mvc i could have astrix in the first parameter. I would like to do that in core as well

Comment: Is `menuPath` more flexible than your example?

Comment: Yes, i should probably have mentioned that. Content is from a CMS, so the menupath is dyanamic